# ssl not work for chrome and safari

Tags: php, html, ssl

I've buy and install SSL for my website, the SSL work in firefox anad lock icon shows in address bar, but my website is not secure in chrome and safari. shall I change anything in my PHP codes? How can I active SSL in these two browser?

Comment: Currently the only detail is that it works with firefox but not with chrome and safari. This is probably not sufficient detail to help. Please add the detailed error messages you get  in these browsers or whatever you get which implies "not secure" for you. It might also be helpful to give the actual domain of your site so one can look at the details of the setup.

Comment: ssl issues are very unlikely to be related to the php code. it's a server config thing. is the certificate encrypted with SHA-1 by any chance? this could be relevant: https://securityintelligence.com/news/browsers-to-end-sha-1-support-in-2017/ . what is the exact error given by chrome and firefox? also inspect your certificate and check the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

some times by adding some codes we can fix this problem. I add these codes at the beginning of my code file

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
$url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

}